# Similar '@isolated' from cucumber-jvm with cucumber-js

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumberjs

Is there a way to achieve the similar as @isolated tag [(here)](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#running-tests-in-isolation) in cucumber-jvm but in cucumber-js ?

Without multiple command, as this is not possible in my env..